# F# open source project hosting using SVN

Tags: open-source, project-hosting, f#, svn

I'm looking to choose open source project hosting site for an F# project using SVN. CodePlex is where the .NET community in general and most F# projects are hosted, but I'm worried TFS + SvnBridge is going to give me headaches. So I'm looking elsewhere and seeking advice here. Or if you think CodePlex is still the best choice in my scenario, I'd like to hear that too. So far, Google Code is looking appealing to me. They have a clean interface and true SVN hosting. But there are close to no F# projects currently hosted (it's not even in their search by programming language list), so I'm wondering if there are any notable downsides besides the lack of community I might encounter. If there is yet another option, I'd like to hear that too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it does not matter how many F# projects are hosted at where you choose to be. Hardly anyone will find your project because it is hosted here or there. People will find your project if it is worthwhile (and judging by your answers on stackoverflow, it is) no matter where it is hosted.

If you insist on using SVN (in 2011!?) I'd go for the technically less complex one, i.e. Google Code. The only bug-free code is code that doesn't run. :)

If you are inclined to switch SCM, be prepared to spend a lot of time to grok the concepts. For a few weeks, your head will probably be all in Version Control instead of what you should be thinking of. I'd just like to add that for me, having made the switch to DVCS, any open source project hosted in SVN is an immediate negative bias. Like, WTF? Don't they know? :)

Comment: Hi @Robert Jeppesen - I'm very flattered by your pre-assessment of the worthwhileness of my project and your appreciation of my answers on stackoverflow! I'm encourage by your advice here, I am probably going to go with Google Code. And believe it or not, SVN is still novel to me, having only switch from Visual Source Safe 6.0 two years ago (some things you can't control)! However, I do indeed intend to learn a DVCS when I get the chance.

Comment: FYI - I decided to go with google code: http://code.google.com/p/unquote/ . So far so good, the svn repository was easy to import from my previous repository using this guide: http://therightstuff.de/CommentView,guid,b984a8e7-e94d-4eed-a705-5dc479f959e8.aspx . Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally choose Codeplex because I know that is where most people go for .Net open source projects (ok, maybe not most people but that is where I would go). However, I'm not attached to one SCM software so it wouldn't be an issue for me.

The way I see it is you can always try Codeplex and if TFS + SvnBridge does in fact give you headaches you can look for another host.

Comment: thanks for your thoughts. I was initially going to trial CodePlex as you suggested, but I'm worried I won't be able to export the repository with full change history if it comes to that: http://brettporter.wordpress.com/2010/09/15/copying-a-codeplex-subversion-repository-with-rsvndump/

Comment: @Stephen Swensen - May I ask why you are hesitant to switch to a new SCM? If you chose Mercurial you wouldn't have issues.

Comment: You know, I considered that, and I am interested in Mercurial, but I just don't have the time for that investment right now (I understand Mercurial is an easy switch for SVN users, but none-the-less).

Comment: @Stephen Your assessment is correct. Switching to DVCS whether it be Git or Mercurial, is very worthwhile, and also a huge time sink.